# Results from PHP doesn't change

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript

I'm currently developing an application in flash that requires me to save data into a remote MySQL database. I use a PHP page to send and receive data from the database and it works fine. However, new updates from the database are not fetched by the PHP page requested by my flash app, even if I reload it. It's like receiving the same old data over and over again. What could possibly wrong with my processes? Can there be a simpler way to access a MySQL through Actionscript without the use of PHP? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding an anti-cache parameter to your request URL like http://dataurl.php?ac=132132333242. Your requests might be getting cached in browser level or flash player level

Comment: you mean I'd just add random 'get variables' in the url?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the query in the php page (attach it)
- Emulate the request without using Flash - use your browser or a network debug proxy like Charles and see what you get
- Are you using [Zend_Amf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.server.html) ?

Using flash to directly access a database is something unusual (to me at the very least). It would require authenticating the Flash application against the database server, sending queries up to it and developing a way of parsing the results. It doesn't make things any simpler and adds a great deal of concerns.